# Using multiple voters from different bundles in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-security

I have initially created a voter in one of my bundles and have used it without a problem. But, I've created another one in another bundle, because it uses different classes and the way it's going to decide if to let users pass is different.

The problem is that this second voter is not detected despite the fact that I've followed the exact same steps as for the first one.

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to create and use only one single voter?

So this is the first one that worked properly, I did it exactly like the documentation says.

Register it as a service

```
services:
  security.access.support_voter:
      class:      SupportMessageBundle\Security\Voter\SupportVoter
      public:     false
      tags:
          - { name: security.voter }
```

Create it. Short explanation of what it does: Checks the curent user's role regarding my `SupportMessageBundle`, a bundle for managing support tickets. I also have a constant that checks if the Ticket was started by the user.

```
namespace SupportMessageBundle\Security\Voter;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\Voter\AbstractVoter;
use MedAppBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class SupportVoter extends AbstractVoter
{
    const SUPPORT = 'support';
    const SUPERADMIN = 'superadmin';
    const MEDIC = 'medic';
    const ISMINE = 'ismine';
    /* const EDIT = 'edit';*/

    protected function getSupportedAttributes()
    {
        return array(self::SUPPORT, self::SUPERADMIN,self::MEDIC,self::ISMINE/*, self::EDIT*/);
    }

    protected function getSupportedClasses()
    {
        return array('MedAppBundle\Entity\User','SupportMessageBundle\Entity\Ticket');
    }

    protected function isGranted($attribute, $object, $user = null)
    {
        // make sure there is a user object (i.e. that the user is logged in)
        if (!$user instanceof UserInterface) {
            return false;
        }

        // double-check that the User object is the expected entity.
        // It always will be, unless there is some misconfiguration of the
        // security system.
        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            throw new \LogicException('The user is somehow not our User class!');
        }

        switch ($attribute) {
            case self::SUPPORT:
                // the data object could have for example a method isPrivate()
                // which checks the Boolean attribute $private
            {

                if ($user->hasRole('ROLE_SUPPORT')||$user->hasRole('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN')) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

                break;
            case self::SUPERADMIN:
                // the data object could have for example a method isPrivate()
                // which checks the Boolean attribute $private
            {

                if ($user->hasRole('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN')) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

                break;
            /*case self::EDIT:
                // this assumes that the data object has a getOwner() method
                // to get the entity of the user who owns this data object
                if ($user->getId() === $post->getOwner()->getId()) {
                    return true;
                }

                break;*/
            case self::MEDIC:
                // the data object could have for example a method isPrivate()
                // which checks the Boolean attribute $private
            {

                if ($user->hasRole('ROLE_MEDIC')) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

                break;

            case self::ISMINE:
                // the data object could have for example a method isPrivate()
                // which checks the Boolean attribute $private
            {

                if ($user == $object->getSender()) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

                break;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

As for the second one,

I register it as a service as well, in the other bundle's `services.yml`:

```
services:

    security.access.features_voter:
        class:      MedAppBundle\Security\Voter\FeaturesVoter
        public:     false
        tags:
            - { name: security.voter }
```

And this time I'm not checking anything, I just return `true`, but calling it returns me `false` every single time, so something is clearly wrong.

```
namespace MedAppBundle\Security\Voter;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\Voter\AbstractVoter;


class FeaturesVoter extends AbstractVoter
{
    const ISMINE = 'ismine';


    protected function getSupportedAttributes()
    {
        return array(self::ISMINE);
    }

    protected function getSupportedClasses()
    {
        return array('MedAppBundle/Entity/Features');
    }

    public function isGranted($attribute, $object, $user = null)
    {
       return true;
    }
}
```

The ways I tried calling it were:

```
$this->isGranted('issmine',$id); //returns false
$this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('issmine', $id, 'Unauthorized access!'); //denies access
```

`$id` is a `Feature` object and this is from a controller in the `MedAppBundle` that contains the `Feature` Entity.

The first voter, however, works properly, so I must be doing something wrong in this one's declarations, or it's not possible to have more than one.

debug:container doesn't list them, not even the working one. The bundles are loaded in Kernel because I've been using controllers and other things from them, just the services seem to not work. All bundles have `$loader->load('services.yml');` inside the DependencyInjection directory in the BundlenameExtension.php file

Comment: Yes you can have multiple voters.  'MedAppBundle:Entity:Features' should be 'MedAppBundle\Entity\Features'.  Take the user class out of the supported classes method.  Might want to dig into AbstractVoter a bit to understand what is happening.

Comment: I did both of those, but still doesn't work. I couldn't find an example where two voters are being defined, everyone keeps defining only one, and I looked a bit on the abstract class, but not sure why my second voter is not called.

Comment: Note that calling the voter doesn't work in either bundle.

Comment: Are you sure the services are even being defined?  Use app/console debug:services to verify.  I have used 8+ different voters in an application.

Comment: Hm, it seems they are not in that list. I don't have debug:services, though. I used debug:container and indeed they are not in that list

Comment: So check the DependencyInjection directory for the bundles and make sure they are loading the services.yml file.  And make sure you loading the bundles in AppKernel.

Comment: Bundles are loaded in Kernel. All bundles have   $loader->load('services.yml'); inside the DependencyInjection directory in the BundlenameExtension.php file